# Remove UILabel top and bottom free space

Tags: swift, uilabel, size

[image]

Hi all. I'm trying to find a way to remove the white space (circled in the screenshot) above and below the text in a UILabel. I googled a lot, but i can't figure out. Thanks for help!

As @Sweeper asks, i attaching my code

```
@IBDesignable final class LabelWithoutPadding: UILabel {
    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        guard let context  = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            // At the first, i thought that it was insets, but this did not help at all
            // So this code doesn't fix my problem
            let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
            super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: insets))
            return
        }
        
        // Source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35335068/how-to-use-coretext-to-replace-uilabel-in-swift
        context.textMatrix = CGAffineTransform.identity;
        // You can see height - 4
        /*
         It helped, but only for the bottom.
         And it seems to me that this is a completely wrong decision.
         Also, some labels stopped showing text because of this and the code below,
         so I think that the solution has not been found.
         */
        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.bounds.size.height - 4);
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0);

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addRect(self.bounds)

        let str = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text ?? "")

        // set font color
        str.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: kCTForegroundColorAttributeName as String), value: self.textColor ?? Colors.contrastHighter , range: NSMakeRange(0, str.length))
        // set font name & size
        let fontRef = self.font ?? FontMaker.getFont(fontSize: 12, fontWeight: 400)
        str.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: kCTFontAttributeName as String), value: fontRef, range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length))

        let frameSetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(str)
        let ctFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(frameSetter, CFRangeMake(0, str.length), path, nil)
        CTFrameDraw(ctFrame, context)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just reduce its height? Please show your code - a [mcve]

Comment: @Sweeper i have updated my question, please check it. Also, i have no height constraints, if that's what you're talking about

Comment: "i have no height constraints" This is why it is important to post your code :-)